# How can I check if user has alread logged in into Windows Active Directory

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory

I've got a problem and since I am new to login/authentication stuff, I do not have clear vision about where to find the answer.

Here is the issue:

I am going to create webapp ( jsf with primefaces + ejb3 ) which allows users be logged into it without login dialog - which means, that all the auth info, about user's roles, groups etc must be gathered from Active Directory. How can I get that ? How can I get users info, if user did not provide at least his or her user name ? What about I must ask Active Directory domain?

Can somebody provide if not working one than at least pseudo-code?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118799/java-sso-kerberos-authentication-against-active-directory

Comment: Interesting issue, but one of my points was to avoid using jcifs stuff - it doesn't look any attractive. Any way - thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Windows systems, Microsoft offers two protocols that are able to do SSO (Single Sign On), which is what you are looking for: NTLM and SPNEGO (a variant of Kerberos).

The answer to your question depends a bit on the operating system your application will run on. If that is Windows, then there are a couple of options that use the Windows API to make it a lot easier. ([mod-auth-sspi](http://mod-auth-sspi.sourceforge.net), [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com))

If you are running other systems, you have to use libraries that provide the whole stack like [Jespa](http://www.ioplex.com), [modauthkerb](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net) or others.

Comment: I've tried to use Waffle and it seems to meet my requirement pretty well! Thank a lot!)