# Java/J2ee Authentication through Window login

Tags: java, windows, authentication, authorization

Can anyone please tell me how to do user authentication through windows corporate domain login id and password... so if the user is already logged in, the application should not ask for username and password.

Whole Scenario: We have a web application that anyone can access.. if you are outside from the company network- do SSO through saml.

If user is on company premises- do the authentication through the machine's username and password.

I hope you got my point.. please let me know if you have any doubt.. 
Note : Webapplication is developed in Java... so solution should be in java.

Answer (score 1):

This Oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/gssapi.html) explains which APIs to use and how. Essentially you need a Java Kerberos integration point. Apache Tomcat has one (if you want to look at how they do it, go [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html#Spring_Security_-_Kerberos_Extension)).

Google also led me to this [project](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/) which might help you.

Lastly have a look at [Java SSO: Kerberos authentication against Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118799/java-sso-kerberos-authentication-against-active-directory).

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if this is the right one

Comment: i am working on it .once i done i will do it thnks again

Answer (score 0):

I think authentication can't be by passed. You have to do it programaticaly rather than asking user to input authentication details.

First get current user's windows login user'name. There must be a login machanism like LDAP for authenticate user to allow him to log-in in windows. Check  this user exist in like LDAP then by pass for web application's authentication machenism.

Comment: I am able to get user's windows login user name .. yes we are using ladp for authentication.. but again how to bypass authentication in my java application ..

Comment: I never did it myself.So i can give you only a guess. Some where in you web application , very fisrt time when a user request for you app. , I think it will be the same place where you check user authenticated or not , take user log-in name and make ldap call to check username exist in ldap.

Comment: Ok ..after checking i fount name is exist.. what is after that .. means there is no need to validate password..just create user session.. i don't think this right approach.. kindly correct me if am wrong ..

Answer (score 0):

you can pass network username and password in the URL like below

[http://username:password@example.com/yourpath/etc](http://username%3apassword@example.com/yourpath/etc)