# Spring Application with SSO using Windows Credentials(via Kerberos)

Tags: spring, spring-security, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have a spring application with a login screen that authenticates credentials that the user has entered with users on our Active Ditectory(using LDAP).
However I'd like to add the capability of SSO , specifically with the Windows Credentials that the user has entered upon logging into Windows.

I'm aware that since AD uses Kerberos it wouldn't be such a "hard" task to do and I've found one possible solution as to how to implement it , specifically [this guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) , with what I want to achieve being on [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#samples-sec-server-win-auth) part of the page.

But honestly I don't seem to be able to understand how to implement it...

I have the following questions:

1)Which parts/classes should I implement for what I actually need , meaning which of the following classes are needed in reality?(AuthProviderConfig , SpnegoConfig , KerberosRestTemplate , KerberosLdapContextSource)

2)If all my users are on a Windows environment do I really need cached tickets(kinit) or keytab? In that case application.yml is also not needed , right?

3)What does the AD admin need to do on his side to configure/enable this SSO with Kerberos?(For the login screen Adapter that works I have the domain, url, rootDn, service user, user searchbase, service user password in my application properties)

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118799/java-sso-kerberos-authentication-against-active-directory) , specifically on what the highest scored answer shows , I'm missing only step 1 and 2(I suppose?).

If anyone has maybe a better "guide" or tips that I can follow in order to implement this I'm all ears.

In any case thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback you could give me.

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered here.  Based on how you've stated your question, I don't think anyone will be able to help you here, except for maybe some broad generalized type of answers which won't be of much use to you.

Comment: Hmm you're right..Should I just rephrase it like "How can I implement SSO for my Spring application using windows Credentials with Kerberos?

Comment: Or what do you suggest I do? I've seen similar questions asked around this topic but none of them had any concrete answers just generalized statements like you mentioned. Moreover when it comes to my case which I didn't find anything aswell...

Answer (score 0):

I realised similiar task using tutorial:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-kerberos

1. You need modificate only WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter - Add there Spnego filter from point 6.2 form this tutorial and beans with KerberosAuthenticationProvider. Spring has built-in kerberos machines that generate and decrypt spnego tokens themselves. On this case in filter you should authenticate all paths but In my case I used kerberos authentication on first time, and later I used JWT token what I had implemented before I implemented SSO.
2. You need keytab file and ServicePrincipalName. You can generate it by kinit with user who have got access to users in AD.
3. I found something like this:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-with-kcd